# There was a required element (&quot;xx-xxxxxx&quot;) that could not be found in QuickBooks

Tags: xml, payment, quickbooks, billing, qbxml

I am trying to query bill payments using QBXML and web connector on a desktop version. Request XML is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>  
   <QBXMLMsgsRq  onError="continueOnError">
       <BillPaymentCheckQueryRq >
           <TxnID >
               xx-xxxxxx
           </TxnID>
       </BillPaymentCheckQueryRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

but in response i get error xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
     <QBXMLMsgsRs>
           <BillPaymentCheckQueryRs statusCode="500" statusSeverity="Warn" statusMessage="The query request has not been fully completed. There was a required element (&quot;xx-xxxxxx&quot;) that could not be found in QuickBooks." />
     </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

I also checked that there is a bill with that TxnId and that bill is also paid with check.

is there any thing else i need to pass in request XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also checked that there is a bill with that TxnId

How did you check this?

The *only way to check this* would have been to do a BillPaymentCheckQuery, which you showed you did above, and which QuickBooks responded telling you that the Bill Payment Check didn't exist.

Note that TxnIDs *do not show up in the QuickBooks GUI*, so you couldn't possibly have checked for it there...

Also, this XML:

```
           <TxnID >
               xx-xxxxxx
           </TxnID>
```

Would check for a `TxnID` value of:

```
"\r\n (lots and lots of spaces here) xx-xxxxx\r\n (lots and lots of spaces here)"
```

You should be passing:

```
<TxnID>xx-xxxxx</TxnID>
```

Finally, you indicate that you:

> I also checked that there is a *bill* with that TxnId

However, you are querying for a `BillPaymentCheck`. If you want to query for a `Bill`, you need to query using `BillQuery`. The `TxnID` value for a `BillPaymentCheck` will NOT be the same as the TxnID for a `Bill`.

Comment: Palmer - consolibyt , i know TxnID of bill , how can i query using it.

Comment: actually i added bill programmatically so i found TxnID in return XML

Comment: It's just as Keith said, if you want to query the bill that you added, you need to do a `BillQuery`, not a `BillPaymentCheckQuery`. In the `BillQuery` add the `TxnID` that you found in your return XML.

Comment: @Hpjchobbes i want to query that for a specific bill how much amount is paid, by which method and on what date ? how can i retrieve this values for specific bill.

Comment: If you want to query for a Bill, you do a BillQuery. You will get back fields like IsPaid, and OpenAmount that tell how much of the bill has been paid already. If you specify <IncludeLinkedTxns>true</IncludeLinkedTxns> in your request, you'll also get back a list of LinkedTxn nodes which will tell you about payments applied to the bill.

Comment: If you need more details than that, you can then use the data in the LinkedTxn nodes to do additional queries for BillPaymentCheck, BillPaymentCreditCard, etc. based on the data in the LinkedTxn.